# Properties of Dirichlet series

Tags: analytic-number-theory, limits-and-convergence, dirichlet-series

I have a question about convergence and properties of Dirichlet series. it seems a bit interesting and different about the convergences of Dirichlet Series  to me.

With $c\in [0,1]$,

$$f(n) = \pm 1,\qquad |\sum_{n\le x} f(n)-x^c|\le 2$$

Let A(x)= $\sum_{n\le x} f(n)$ be  a Summatory Function.And F(S)=$\sum_n f(n)n^{-s}$ be a Dirichlet series.

**So Why and How;**

$\sum_n f(n) n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s) > c$ and $\sum_n |f(n)|n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s) > 1$ ?

Here is a referrence https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962712/polynomial-growth. i tried to solve it by using this theorem in this link.I also  have looked a lot of books and article , and have searched to find it.

In general , i look at Analytic Number theory and Multiplicative Number Theory, but I couldn't see the form and way of solution of this question. May you help me ? you can also suggest me referrences or hints.Thanks.

Comment: You define $A$ and $F$, but you don't do anything with them. Since $|f(n)|=1$ for all $n$, your second series is just $\sum_nn^{-s}$, the Riemann zeta function. Are you really asking "why and how" the series for the zeta function converges for real part of $s$ greater than one?

Comment: i am curious about that; You only see that part of all Question? i can already see that the abscissa of absolute  convergence is 1 because of Riemann Zeta. i dont have a problem there. Please Look at integrity of question. there is $x^c$ there and says that convergence is $\sigma_c=c$ of F(s) and i especially think that part and said why? we know that always  $\sigma_c ≤ \sigma_a$ .so the  $\sigma_c≤ 1$. what else have i to think about it?

Comment: ok. i see ! we know  $0≤ \sigma_a-\sigma_c ≤1$. if we put $\sigma_a=1$ in the inequality,  from here $\sigma_c ∈ [0,1]=c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating/summing by parts allows you to prove that if $\sum A(n)/n^{s+1}$ converges then $\sum f(n)/n^s$ converges, which gives you the requested convergence.   In general, the region where a Dirichlet series is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent can be up to width 1, but no larger.

Titchmarsh's Theory of Functions has a thorough chapter on Dirichlet series with many results like these (it also comes up in his Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function)

Comment: Very good comment. Thanks a lot:) I will investigate and analyze the book now.